# When does vector::push_back increase capacity?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm using a bunch of `std::vectors` by setting their capacity at the beginning and using `push_back` to slowly fill them up. Most of these vectors will have the same size (16 elements), although some might get larger. If I use `push_back` 16 times on a vector with size 0 and capacity 16 initially, can I be sure that capacity will be exactly 16 after the `push_backs`?

Comment: Should be the case, have you tried?

Comment: When you added more elements than the current capacity the vector will increase capacity.

Comment: Don't reserve capacity at all until you have demonstrated a performance gain in a critical component of your application. Pure premature optimization.

Comment: @djechlin: It can also be done to ensure iterator/pointer validity, with no interest in optimization at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes -- once you reserve a specific capacity, the vector will not be reallocated until you exceed the capacity you've set<sup>1</sup>. Exactly how many more items you may be able to push without reallocation isn't specified, but you are guaranteed at least that many.

---

1. In particular, pointers and iterators into the vector are guaranteed to remain valid until you exceed the specified capacity.

Answer (score 2):

`23.3.6.5 [vector modiﬁers]`

```
void push_back(const T& x);
void push_back(T&& x);
```

> Remarks: Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity

Pretty much self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Yup.

23.3.6.3p6:

> No reallocation shall take place during insertions that happen after a call to `reserve()` until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the value of `capacity()`.